# auth:api middleware not working in live server using laravel

Tags: react-native, laravel-5

auth:api middleware not working in live server using laravel

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'business_entry_api','middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    // function here 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you ca go with `auth('api')->user()`. It'll return the authenticated user even if middleware is not specifically used.

use like below on your api file:

```
public function __construct()
    {     
          $this->middleware(function ($request,Closure $next) {
            $this->user = Auth('api')->user();
            return $next($request);
        });
    }
```